# Enabling cURL for automated PHP install on IIS 7

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, curl, automation

I'm trying to enable cURL in PHP when *.php files resolve in IIS sites.  Before I would install PHP the old fashion way and edit the php.ini file and just enable cURL by uncommenting this line:

extension=php_curl.dll

Now that the PHP install is automated in Windows for version 5.3.5, I'm not really sure what Windows did, or where to enable cURL.  How can it be enabled in PHP 5.3.5?

http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx

Also, do I need to do anything special in IIS for PHP files to be understood?  I used to follow this guide, but again, now that the PHP install is automated, I don't even know how I can use these instructions.

http://www.howtogeek.com/50432/how-to-install-php-on-iis-7-for-windows-server-2008/

## EDIT:

So it looks like PHP will work in IIS 7 from the automated install.  I found the Handler Mapping for *.php.  So now I just need to figure out how to turn on cURL in PHP.  Maybe I do it the same way.  But in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the missing part.  cURL is already enabled by default in PHP 5.3.5.

```
C:\>iisreset

Attempting stop...
Internet services successfully stopped
Attempting start...
Internet services successfully restarted

C:\>
```

Test it!

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP cURL Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<?php
    echo function_exists('curl_version');
?>

 </body>
</html>
```